'_PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape' when calling resnet_v2.preprocess_input()
I keep running into this error when trying to preprocess my datasets:

AttributeError: '_PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'. Did you mean: 'save'?

I'm currently using ResNet, but I've also tried the preprocess functions for MobileNet and NasNet. It almost looks like it's an issue with imagenet_utils.py, but I assume that's not the case.
Is there any way I can fix this other than switching to a new application?
This is my code:
trainingdata = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory='archive/chest_xray/train/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='int',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(512,512)
)

validationdata = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory='archive/chest_xray/test/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='int',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(512,512)
)

td = keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input(trainingdata)

Here is my full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\You\Documents\keras models\PNEUMONIA.PY", line 25, in <module>
    td = keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input(trainingdata)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\You\Documents\keras models\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\applications\resnet_v2.py", line 134, in preprocess_input
    return imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\You\Documents\keras models\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\applications\imagenet_utils.py", line 106, in preprocess_input
    return _preprocess_tensor_input(x, data_format=data_format, mode=mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\You\Documents\keras models\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\applications\imagenet_utils.py", line 254, in _preprocess_tensor_input
    ndim = len(x.shape)
               ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_PrefetchDataset' object has no attribute 'shape'. Did you mean: 'save'?


@LukeL OP did post the line - td = keras.applications.resnet_v2.preprocess_input(trainingdata). Python tracebacks put the most recent call last; ndim = len(x.shape) is in a keras file, not OP's code.

This question is similar to: Extract target from Tensorflow PrefetchDataset. The question's not exactly the same, but they get at the same problem & the solutions there should mostly apply here as well.

@AndrewYim Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I cannot rely too much on tensorflow because of difficulty making the backend work on WSL2. I tried the top answer there (converting my PrefetchDataset into a list and converting it to a tf.data.Dataset), but it threw more errors. I can't paste the full traceback here (too long), but it boils down to tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Pack as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a float tensor but is a int32 tensor [Op:Pack] name: 0. Is there anyway I can solve this with the Torch backend?

Can you post some example images to make this easier to test? If it's a HIPAA issue or something, dummy data would be fine - just something so we can easily reproduce the problem.

The accepted answer notes that "for more complex datasets (e.g. nested dictionaries) you will need more preprocessing after calling list(ds)" - this might be one of those cases.

@AndrewYim Thanks again for the reply. I've already figured out a workaround as you can see in my other comment. But, on the off chance that you still are interested in finding out what went wrong, you can find my full code as I was just running it a few minutes ago here: https://pastebin.com/bntb3c0R. And, thankfully, there is no HIPAA issue. This is a school project and I'm using a publicly available dataset that can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia

Found a workaround by adding keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input() as a layer in between an input layer and the premade model, like so:
input = keras.layers.Input([224, 224, 3])

pre = keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input(input)

net = keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
    input_tensor = pre,
    alpha=1.0,
    include_top=True,
    weights=None,
    classes=3,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
    name=None,
)
model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=net.output)

Technically a different function than in the original question, but ultimately they both end up calling keras\src\applications\imagenet_utils.py and produce the same error when they do, so this should hopefully work for all preprocess_input functions that end up calling this.
